# Is there a verb for "walking with joy"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Two good friends see each other after many years. They are happy and have a lot to talk about. They are headed towards somewhere together, laughing.

What is the most appropriate single word to describe their joyful walk? I am looking for a verb to replace *walk* with.

Comment: This is a situation which is perfectly suited for a thesaurus. Look up 'walk' and check out the list of synonyms for those that are have happy connotations.

Comment: Following Mitch's suggestion, [**saunter**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/saunter) has positive connotations, but it doesn't necessarily entail "joy", a "joyful saunter" doesn't sound great, but a "joyful stroll" does.

Comment: I was going to say that I doubted there were single words to denote walking while being in particular moods, but then I thought that there were words which might fit that description for negative moods, *trudge*, *schlep* or *drag* for example. So I don't have any suggestions other than to look for antonyms of those. Is there a particular reason you don't want to just add 'joyfully' to 'walk' or to some other mood-neutral walk synonym? Also, it might help you to think about how you see their movement itself being different due to mood and see if that leads you to any words.

Answer (score 12):

The friends went on a walk with a *spring in their step*.

[***spring in one's step***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spring_in_one%27s_step)

> *(idiomatic) enthusiasm, energy or a positive outlook or cheerful
>   attitude.*

Answer (score 4):

Saunter:

> walk in a slow, relaxed manner, without hurry or effort.

Amble:

> a walk at a slow, relaxed pace, especially for pleasure

Promenade:

> take a leisurely walk, ride, or drive in public, especially to meet or
>   be seen by others.

Amble probably works best of the 3.

Answer (score 3):

**stroll**

> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stroll)
>
> to walk slowly in usually a pleasant and relaxed way

Answer (score 2):

Also **skip** describes the physical movement, but would indicate the mood. Mostly used for children.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest prance:
prance
prɑːns/Submit
verb
1.
(of a horse) move with high springy steps.
"the pony was prancing around the paddock"

Comment: Welcome to the ELU :-). Can you please provide a reference for the definition? It would substantially improve your answer (as suggested [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)).

Answer (score 2):

They were so ecstatic at seeing each other again that they were walking on air. 
"walking on air" idiom meaning amazingly happy"

Answer (score 2):

What about Jaunting.

> jaunt
>   jônt/
>   verb
>   go on a short excursion or journey for pleasure.
>   "they went jaunting through Ireland"

Answer (score 1):

ebullient (adj) / ebullience (n) / ebulliently (adv) - cheerful and full of energy - may fit your bill

- He wasn't his normal ebullient self - http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/ebullient
- The award winner was in an ebullient mood at the dinner in her honor - http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ebullient
- If you describe someone as ebullient, you mean that they are lively and full of enthusiasm - http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ebullient
- Stories of New York Citys public schools crumbling while officials demand billion-dollar bond issues to rebuild them call to mind a day in June 1988, when Mayor Ed Koch, flanked by cameramen and reporters, ebulliently announced that subway service would be restored on the reopened Williamsburg Bridge - http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ebullient

Comment: Welcome to the ELU :-). Can you please provide a reference for the definition? It would substantially improve your answer (as suggested [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Comment: I made up the sentence to show possible usage ... I'll look online for a real example

Comment: Done ... may have gone a little overboard :S

Comment: No, it's quite good. I liked your example as well - there's nothing wrong with inventing a sentence, it's just that references help other users find more information, and it gives proof that your answer is valid. I also like the word *ebullient*, haven't heard it before

Answer (score 0):

The friends walked in bliss.

Bliss

1. Perfect happiness or joy (http://www.google.com/search?q=bliss)

Answer (score 0):

***joyous, bouncing walk***

> [William Faulkner: The Contemporary Reviews](https://books.google.ca/books?id=57cUKRJIY5kC&pg=PA132&dq=%22bouncing%20walk%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XnY9VcrmKuOxsATXlIGIAw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22bouncing%20walk%22&f=false) - Page 132 M. Thomas Inge -
>   1995
>
> Thus, the reporter is known by his flapping coat, Jiggs the mechanic
>   by **his bouncing walk**, and Laverne by her “savage mealcolored hair.”

Answer (score 0):

reminisce, reminiscing

eg.

They were reminiscing the past, oblivious of time and their surroundings.

Comment: Welcome to the ELU :-). A more detailed answer (with a definition not just an example, and a reference to the dictionary the definition would be from) would be much more helpful, for both the OP and future users. That being said, while reminiscence implies some enjoyment, it has nothing to do with walking, so your example doesn't seem to fit OP's needs (IMO)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I would second the word Jaunt (or in this case would use jauntily) and do away with the word walk (and its synonyms) all together.

so to modify the original statement:

Two good friends see each other after many years. They are happy and have a lot to talk about. They jauntily headed towards somewhere together, laughing.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! As you say, this ought to be a comment and as such is likely to be deleted. If you expand upon this answer instead - by providing links to online dictionaries and examples of its use - this would be a great answer! Try that, then you will earn enough reputation for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this word while researching for an appropriate word for the context in question.

The word is **bimble**

Though it is mentioned as informal, I thought it suits the context well.

Oxford dictionary defines it as,

> [**bimble**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bimble)  ˈbɪmb(ə)l/
>
> British Informal
>
> **verb**
>
> 1. walk or travel at a leisurely pace.
>
> > "on Sunday we bimbled around Spitalfields and Brick Lane"
>
> **noun**
>
> 1. a leisurely walk or journey.
>
> > "we were enjoying a pleasant bimble over the rocks"